# Catch22 with almost-duplicate contacts (not recognized but can't change)

Tags: contact, duplicate-management, merge, duplicate-matching-rule

I have pairs of Contact records that ought to be merged. The dupes are obvious to humans (e.g. if one is Fred Hampton, the other might be Hampton Frederick or FredHampton FredHampton), but SF says **We found no potential duplicates of this Contact.** In other words, Step #1 in SF's "[Merge Duplicate Contacts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.contacts_merge_lex.htm&type=5)" instructions is not happening.

When I try to edit the names, if I make them similar enough (not even identical) that SF recognizes the duplicate, it refuses to let me save the change because they're duplicates.

SF isn't detecting the dupes, and it won't let me make them detectable. Catch 22.

How do I force SF to merge dupes that it thinks are not dupes?

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.contacts_merge.htm&type=5 is a good start

Comment: @identigral I already looked at that. Those instructions only work if Salesforce detects potential duplicates, which it is not doing for me.

Comment: As you pointed out, when you edit the names to make them similar enough, they'll be detected as dupes. This would be the easiest solution. You can also create your own duplicate matching rules in addition to out of the box rules.

Comment: The sentence you're referencing ends with ... "it refuses to let me save the change". It detects the potential dupe while I'm editing.

Comment: You can change that behavior, the docs cover this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have control over this behavior as you can [customize duplicate rules](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.duplicate_rules_create.htm&type=5).

It sounds like your rule **blocks** the action on **edit**. If you select **allow**, you'd be able to edit it to "match" so it'd be caught.

[image]

In terms of your issue at hand, it does sound like you'd be better served creating a more complicated [matching rule](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.matching_rules_create.htm&type=5) to catch the situation you're describing so you don't need to manually edit it to flag it. Utilizing some [fuzzy matching](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.matching_rules_matching_methods.htm&type=5) on first/last name may help.